# How to get list of shared links of files of a folder in Dropbox

Tags: javascript, image, dropbox-api, dropbox-sdk-js

I have a folder (Photos/Sample Album) in Dropbox. What I want to do is display all the images in that folder on my website.
Solution I have been able to come up with is following: 
Use [Metadata](https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/docs#metadata) API to get all the files of the folder. Then I can use [Media](https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/docs#media) API or [ShareLink](https://www.dropbox.com/developers-v1/core/docs#shares).
But to do get sharelinks for n files, I will need to make (n+1) calls, call for each file. Is there a faster way to do this ? Can I just make one call get all the links for specified folder.
I am trying to make these calls in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

No, unfortunately the Dropbox API doesn't currently provide a way to get these links in bulk. We'll consider it a feature request.

Comment: Until then what is the best way to get shared links... I mean of 2000 files in one folder. It seems crazy to make 2000 API calls!!!

Comment: @Llewellyn Thanks for the feedback. One new note on this, if the links have already been created, you can use [/2/sharing/list_shared_links](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#sharing-list_shared_links) to list them in bulk. The API doesn't offer a way to create them in bulk though.

Comment: @SethKitchen No, no change on this. You can list existing links using /2/sharing/list_shared_links, but there still isn't a way to create new ones in bulk.